# sql select (..) where id in (list_of_values) vs select (...) where id in (subquery)

Tags: sql-server, performance

This is my first post on Stackoverflow. :-)

I use an SQL server, which has a huge table (up to 50'000'000 records), and a smaller table (up to 500'000 records).

Let's consider two queries:

**Query A**

```
SELECT *
FROM my_huge_table
WHERE column_name IN(list_of_values)
```

versus **Query B**

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_huge_table 
WHERE column_name IN (
    SELECT column_name
    FROM smaller_table
    WHERE ...
)
```

The subquery in query B returns exactly the same list as `list_of_values` in query A.

The length of list_of_values in query A is limited (as described in many places on web). If my list_of_values is long (eg: 10'000), I have to split it into chunks, but when I use query B, it works fine, although results from the subquery from query B *also* contains 10'000 records...

What is more when I use query B, it is faster than query A. I looked into execution plans and it shows that query B uses some parallel calculations (I'm not familiar with execution plans).

**Questions**

1. In my script I have a list of values, I cannot easily create a subquery. Is there any way to execute something similar to query B using list of values?
2. Why is query B faster than query A?
3. Are there any other optimizations to be done?

PS: I've already created an index on the queried column.

Thanks.

Comment: Please always ask only one question. And why use `IN()`? Joins would probably be better.

Comment: You could write your list of values to a temporary table first. That would get rid of your limit.

Comment: Thanks cdev!!! so simple and so fast!